# Gcloud sdk install for Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have an issue to install the gcloud sdk on my mac. I have the following error when I do the `./install.sh`. Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 32, in <module>
    import setup  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import platforms
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

And when I do `gcloud init`

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 62, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 26, in <module>
    import re as stdlib_re  # Avoid confusion with the re we export.
  File "/Users/kevin/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 124, in <module>
    import enum
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('enum')
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

I think this is a Python issue. but I'm running Python3:

`python -V` shows

```sh
Python 3.9.0
```

I have installed it with homebrew.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Sorry you're having problems! This is a known issue that is in the process of being resolved: https://b.corp.google.com/issues/170125513

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue across Mac, Windows and Linux: https://issuetracker.google.com/170125513.

I'd suggest to use the recommended Python versions mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#mac) (3.5 to 3.8).

Also this does not affect only to Cloud SDK but others as well (for example as mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue41958)).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a quick fix you can add this to your bash profile and restart your terminal:

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8`

Worked for me

Comment: This worked for me as well, super good answer! For mac users like myself:
`brew install python@3.8`
and `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3`
Its nice to add the export to your `~/.bash_profile` file as well (or w/e shell you use)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it works with the version 3.8.6 of python.
I will add some infos if it can help somebody. In order to manage python version, I have used [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and installed the version of python I needed.

```sh
pyenv install 3.8.6
pyenv global 3.8.6
```

Comment: I have switched to older python3 with `brew install python@3.8; brew unlink python3; brew link python@3.8`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.